# Disable navigation keys in Android

Tags: android, android-service, navigationbar, android-windowmanager

How can I disable navigation keys via Service in Android? I had been thinking about adding *FLAG_FULLSCREEN* or *FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN* to `WindowManager` in order to make a service go fullscreen, but it didn't work. Next thing I did trying to disable TypeGuard, but no luck. Anyone worked with KeyguardManager because it might solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

And add permission   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>` in AndroidManifest.xml.

OR

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```